# Haxe enum assign value

Tags: enums, haxe

I need to port a C-like enum to Haxe:

```
enum Items
{
item1,
item2=0x00010000,
item3=0x00010001,
item4,
};
```

But Haxe doesn't allow default value it seems. How can I do this?

My real enum has hundreds of entries and for those with default values I must preserve the values.

Answer (score 3):

You would typically use an [enum abstract](https://haxe.org/manual/types-abstract-enum.html) for this:

```
@:enum abstract Items(Int) {
    var Item1 = 0x00000000;
    var Item2 = 0x00010000;
    var Item3 = 0x00010001;
    var Item4 = 0x00010010;
}
```

With Haxe 4, you can write `enum` instead of `@:enum` and also omit values like in C-style enums:

```
enum abstract Items(Int) {
    var Item1;
    var Item2 = 0x00010000;
    var Item3 = 0x00010001;
    var Item4;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Haxe Enum manual](https://haxe.org/manual/types-enum-instance.html), there's no default values. But, maybe you'll describe the problem better? Probably it should be solved by objects not enums?